# Grid column header grouping is incorrect

Tags: extjs

Grid column header grouping is incorrect in Google Chrome und Edge, but it's works in Firefox.

Test with ExtJS 6.0 - 7.5

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSRlo.png) of detail

A bug  can be reproduced with code

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    columnLines: true,
    
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone ...', columns: [
                { text: 'Phone1', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone2', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone3', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone4', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone5', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone6', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone7', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone8', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone9', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' },
                { text: 'Phone10', width : 75, dataIndex: 'phone' }
            ]}
        ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you are trying to report a bug you should do so at the respective Chrome/Edge developer websites.

Comment: How do I work around this bug?

Comment: I could not reproduce the bug in google chrome, edge browsers on MacOs.